# Explain this NY Times Mini Crossword clue from Sept 20, 2022

Tags: crossword-clues, explanation

In [The Mini Crossword](https://www.nytimes.com/crosswords/game/mini/2022/09/20) in the New York Times for Tuesday, September 20, 2022, there is a clue:

> What "taxes," "wonkery" and "I mean" are each anagrams of [5 letters]

And the answer is:

> STATE

How does that answer make any sense?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer makes sense because each of the three are anagrams of:

> **US states**

> taxes -> **Texas**

> wonkery -> **New York**

> I mean -> **Maine**

Comment: This is probably the correct explanation, but it surprises me that such a clue in a plural tense would have a singular answer. Perhaps the setter tried to fix this with the "each"? I think "or"/"are an" would have been clearer.

Comment: @ash4fun The clue isn't in the plural: *what* can refer to something either singular or plural, and the *are* is plural because of the three anagrams, not the answer. Consider the equivalent 'What France, Germany and the Netherlands are each neighbours of' (answer: Belgium).

Comment: @dbmag9 you're right, of course, but it is also true that the _each_ is misleading and even, arguably, wrong. They aren't _each_ anagrams of "state", they are _all_ anagrams of "state".

Comment: @terdon I think both are equally grammatical and clear, to be honest. Shem, Ham and Japheth are each sons of Noah; 2, 3 and 101 are each prime numbers; 'the Big Apple', 'the City that Never Sleeps' and 'the Melting Point' are each nicknames of New York City.

Comment: They atl all **sons** of Noah, each is a **son** of Noah.

Comment: "Anagrams of *a state*" would be the correct expression, but articles are skipped in a crossword.